# PL/SQL: procedure to process a comparison between two tables

Tags: sql, plsql

This is an example what i need :

Table 1 :

```
Id  champ1 champ2 champ3
   1      A      S      Q
   2      D      K      A
   3      D      A      S
```

Table 2:

```
Id  champ1 champ2 champ3
   1      A      S      Q
   2      Q      A      A
   3      A      A      K
```

A procedure that feeds a table3 as a result of comparison between the table 1 and table 2

Table 3:

```
Id_exc name_champ noted_val except_val
   2    champ1       D         Q
   3    champ1       D         A
   2    champ2       K         A
   3    champ3       S         K
```

Please, i need help if someone had the same challenge :)

Comment: What kind of comparison?

Comment: I need to compare between data on table 1 and data on table 2 , this procedure  feeds a table 3 if a data is not a same in the two tables.

Comment: @user3441432 your description of the problem is pretty good, if you would include what you have tried the votes would probably go in the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Id int, champ1 varchar2(1), champ2 varchar2(1), champ3 varchar2(1))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (1, 'A', 'S', 'Q')
    INTO Table1 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (2, 'D', 'K', 'A')
    INTO Table1 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (3, 'D', 'A', 'S')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (Id int, champ1 varchar2(1), champ2 varchar2(1), champ3 varchar2(1))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table2 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (1, 'A', 'S', 'Q')
    INTO Table2 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (2, 'Q', 'A', 'A')
    INTO Table2 (Id, champ1, champ2, champ3)
         VALUES (3, 'A', 'A', 'K')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

The below query would give you the differences

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ((SELECT * 
         FROM   table1 
         minus 
         SELECT * 
         FROM   table2) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   table2 
         minus 
         SELECT * 
         FROM   table1)); 

ID  CHAMP1  CHAMP2  CHAMP3
2   D   K   A
2   Q   A   A
3   A   A   K
3   D   A   S
```

Comment: The query give the differencd,  but i need a query or procedure with PL/SQL to feeds the table 3 with the diffents between the two tables

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e30ef/2/0)

Here is a query that gets the result, although it's ugly:

```
SELECT
   t1.id AS Id_exc, 'champ1' AS name_champ, t1.champ1 AS noted_val, t2.champ1 AS except_val
FROM
   Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id WHERE t1.champ1 <> t2.champ1

UNION

SELECT
   t1.id AS Id_exc, 'champ2' AS name_champ, t1.champ2 AS noted_val, t2.champ2 AS except_val
FROM
   Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id WHERE t1.champ2 <> t2.champ2

UNION

SELECT
   t1.id AS Id_exc, 'champ3' AS name_champ, t1.champ3 AS noted_val, t2.champ3 AS except_val
FROM
   Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id WHERE t1.champ3 <> t2.champ3
```

Comment: Code doesnt look that ugly but definitely serves the purpose. So + 1

Comment: @realspirituals thanks for adding the fiddle, I find your way of comparing also quite interesting, it is more dynamic. +1

Answer (score 0):

create OR replace procedure P_test is

q varchar2(4000 byte);

V_SELECT    VARCHAR2(2000):= NULL;

begin

for rec in ( select COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns where table_name='TABLE1' and column_name <> 'ID_T') loop

V_SELECT := NULL;

V_SELECT := V_SELECT || rec.COLUMN_NAME;

q := 'SELECT t1.id_t AS Id,'''|| V_SELECT ||''' AS nom_champ, t1.'||V_SELECT||' AS noted, t2.'||V_SELECT ||' AS excepted '||

'FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.id_t = t2.id_t WHERE t1.'||V_SELECT||' <> t2.'||V_SELECT;

q := 'INSERT INTO TABLE3 ' || q;

dbms_output.put_line('Query : ' || q);

execute immediate q;

end loop;      
end;